# ButterKnife + MaterialDrawer

Tags: android, butterknife

Есть класс, типа хелпер, для бокового меню, внутри используется библиотека `MaterialDrawer`

```
public class NavigationDrawer {

    private Drawer drawer;

    @BindView(R.id.drawer_footer_logo) ImageView footerLogo;

    @OnClick(R.id.drawer_footer_logo)
    public void onFooterLogoClick() {
         close():
         if(drawerListener != null) {
             drawerListener.onFooterLogoClick();
        }
    }

    public NavigationDrawer(Activity activity) {
         drawer = new DrawerBuilder()
             .withActivity(activity)
             .withHeader(R.layout.drawer_header)
             .withFooter(R.layout.drawer_footer)
             //etc..
             .build();
         ButterKnife.bind(this, drawer.getDrawerLayout());
    }

public void close() {
    drawer.close();
}

    //etc..

}
```

При нажатии на лого ничего не происходит (должно закрыться боковое меню). Если я меняю `@OnClick` на `setOnClickListener` после `ButterKnife.bind`, то приложение падает на NPE. Что не так?

Comment: Имхо, `ButterKnife` хорош для AAA, в MV-подобных архитектурах - НЕТ, вот, живой пример, вынес вью в отдельный класс и `ButterKnife` бессилен

Comment: Очень странно обвинять библиотеки, в частных случаях, тем более в архитектурах, что такое AAA? MV структуры? Если вы имеете ввиду Model View , то они все очень разные,  ах да - живой пример это не показывает и проблема совершена не в этом.

Comment: @Shwarz Andrei, да, простите, погорячился)

Comment: Но минусовать то зачем?

Answer (score 1):

ИМХО вы пытаетесь биндить не тот контент.

Попробуйте:

```
ButterKnife.bind(this, drawer.getContent());
```

P.S. Как предупреждает автор ButterKnife:

> A butter knife is like a dagger only infinitely less sharp.

ну то есть грубо говоря - осторожно, не порежтесь :)

Comment: `getContent` возвращает корневой `View` в котором `DrawerLayout`?

Comment: Он возвращает `FrameLayout` внутри которого размещаются остальные вьюшки

Comment: Не помогло, тот же NPE